# How many bitcoins would it require for a sustained DOS attack on bitcoin network?

Tags: network, attack

How many bitcoins would it require for a sustained DOS attack on bitcoin network?

Without transaction fee, how many bitcoins would that be?

How many transactions could we generate with 1 BTC everyday (without fee)?

Comment: 7 transactions per second times 60 equals per minute times 60 equals per hour times 24 equals per day = 604800 satoshis sent in individual transactions. However, nodes filter such so-called "dust" transactions. The minimum output amount for a transaction to be relayed by the network is 546 satoshis. So: 330220800 satoshis = 3.302208 BTC to fill the network for a day. http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/37z9ln/how_much_btc_needed_to_fill_entire_1_mb_block/crqzv63

Comment: It appears that you posted an answer as a comment. Please rather answer your own question instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

7 transactions per second times 60 equals per minute times 60 equals per hour times 24 equals per day = 604800 satoshis sent in individual transactions.

However, nodes filter such so-called "dust" transactions. The minimum output amount for a transaction to be relayed by the network is 546 satoshis. So: 330220800 satoshis = 3.302208 BTC to fill the network for a day.

(As explained in, http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/37z9ln/how_much_btc_needed_to_fill_entire_1_mb_block/crqzv63)

Comment: This answer does not take into account minimum fee rates or competitive fee rate environments which are the primary platform in which potential "DOS" attacks could be effectively attempted on Bitcoin. It also does not take into account that in order to effectively DOS an entire block a pool would need to execute it against the probably much more valuable and high quality chains produced by other pools. Thus you would effectively need to add in the rate at which a pool can be bribed to essentially commit career suicide by attempting such a thing.